# Animate easy in and easy out when hover a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys i want to make a menu similar to this site: http://tommasoraspo.com/creativepartners/DesignLovers/index.html

But I don't know how i would animate the Bookmark to show up when i hover a link. I thought in using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) (slideInDown animation) but then it would only show up when hover over but wouldn't get back when hover out.

Initiate Animation on Hover:

```
function animationHover(element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    element.hover(
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated ' + animation);        
        },
        function(){
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);         
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you point to isn't using an javascript.  Rather, they are using css3 transitions to animate the background position of an image that is "off-canvas" when the site is loaded.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2gpjG/) with the relevant css/html.

You may have to tweak the values to suit your specific design and image.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
ul.nav li.current a, ul.nav li a:hover {
    background-position: 50% 0;
}
ul.nav li a {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/70/abstract/) no-repeat 50% -90px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.2s linear;
    transition: background-position 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: It was easier than i thought! Thank you!